# Why data constructor is not in scope here

Tags: haskell, statistics, t-test

I am trying to do Student T-test as provided [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.0.0/docs/Statistics-Test-StudentT.html):

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Statistics.Test.StudentT
sampleA = V.fromList [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4]
sampleB = V.fromList [2.0,4.0,5.0,5.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6]
main = print $ StudentT sampleA sampleB SamplesDiffer
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
rnunttest.hs:8:16: error:
    Data constructor not in scope:
      StudentT :: Vector Double -> Vector Double -> PositionTest -> a0
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The data constructor is `StudenTTest`, not `StudentT`.

Comment: Ok. Yes, it works with `studentTTest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made two mistakes here:

1. the function is `studenTTest`, not `StudentT`, that is the name of the *type* constructor; and
2. the constructor takes a `PositionTest` foollowed by two vectors.

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Statistics.Test.StudentT

sampleA = V.fromList [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4]
sampleB = V.fromList [2.0,4.0,5.0,5.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6]

main = print (studentTTest SamplesDiffer sampleA sampleB)
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
Prelude V Statistics.Test.StudentT> main
Just (Test {testSignificance = mkPValue 1.351738152442984e-2, testStatistics = -2.8243130467507513, testDistribution = studentT 14.0})
```

Comment: is not that with lower case?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to change the constructor to `studentTTest`

```
main = print $ studentTTest sampleA sampleB SamplesDiffer
```